# How to reset gluster volume top list

Tags: glusterfs

I'm new at gluster file system.
I want reset list of

```
# gluster volume top write list-cnt 10
```

this.
cuz I fixed some invalid writing and reading actions.
I need to recount write and read count.
Thanks.